# How to create WPF Dispatcher in Windows Service

Tags: wpf, service, .net-5

We have a windows service, and part of the job of the windows service is to send emails. Our applications allow users to save the filtering on a grid (third party) and give that a view name. The view name can then be used in a task that creates the grid, loads up the filtering for the view of the data, and then gets a string filter expression from the grid. The string filter expression is then fed to [DynamicLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq) and used in a Linq "Where" statement to get the data as the user would see it. The problem with this approach is needing WPF to allow the code to create the grid, filter and send email.

Using this [reference](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/) we tried to run tasks. It works in a regular WPF app, but not when run from our windows service. This is our task code (**Code 1**):

```
public class OurTask
{
    public void RunTask ()
    {
        // Do some setup

       Action createGridAction =
                ( Action )
                (
                    () =>
                    {
                         // create grid, load view, get filter expression
                         // get filtered data
                    }
                );

            // create a thread
            var newWindowThread = new Thread ( new ThreadStart ( () =>
            {
                // create our context, and install it:
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext (
                    new DispatcherSynchronizationContext (
                        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher ) );

                LogProvider.Logger.LogInfo ( "RunTask Call CreateGrid" );

                createGridAction ();

                LogProvider.Logger.LogInfo ( "RunTask Called CreateGrid" );
            } ) );

            // use data to create email with data view and send email

    }

}
```

We also have code like this in a number of places (**Code 2**):

```
       Action notifyAction =
                ( Action )
                (
                    () =>
                    {
                       // do something
                    }
                );  

            if ( System.Windows.Application.Current != null && 
                 System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread )
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke ( notifyAction, 
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.DataBind );
            else
               notifyAction ();
```

We want to setup a dispatcher that will run Code 1 but we would also like to
set the App Dispatcher so that Code 2 would work. How can we at least get Code 1 running
and ideally set the App Dispatcher so Code 2 runs?

**Update**
Took @BionicCode advice and created a server client that has no UI and
handles the code for grid. Thanks

Comment: WPF classes are designed for desktop applications, not any service apps (Windows service apps or IIS web apps). Why sending emails requires WPF classes?

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the question. It lays out why we are doing this. I would not normally do this either, but using the grid to get a string filter expression that is converted to predicate, by dynamic linq is why we are doing this.

Comment: _"The problem with this approach is needing WPF to allow the code to create the grid, filter and send email."_ You already nailed it. Your problem is your service is doing too much. A service has no UI. A service runs in the background. A service uses a different threading model and doesn't support UI threads (dispatcher threads), same applies to a console application. A service interacts with other services or clients, but not with users. What you need is a client (of your service) that has a UI and allows to interact with a user. This client can be a desktop client.